# Using Action Method to Return Image in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show an image using an action method. Here is my action method in Account controller:

```
public ActionResult CaptchaImage(string prefix, bool noisy = true)
    {
        var rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        //generate new question
        int a = rand.Next(10, 99);
        int b = rand.Next(0, 9);
        var captcha = string.Format("{0} + {1} = ?", a, b);

        //store answer
        Session["Captcha" + prefix] = a + b;

        //image stream
        FileContentResult img = null;

        using (var mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(130, 30))
        using (var gfx = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)bmp))
        {
            gfx.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
            gfx.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gfx.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.White, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

            //add noise
            if (noisy)
            {
                int i, r, x, y;
                var pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    pen.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(
                    (rand.Next(0, 255)),
                    (rand.Next(0, 255)),
                    (rand.Next(0, 255)));

                    r = rand.Next(0, (130 / 3));
                    x = rand.Next(0, 130);
                    y = rand.Next(0, 30);

                    gfx.DrawEllipse(pen, (float)x, (float)y, (float)r, (float)r);
                }
            }

            //add question
            gfx.DrawString(captcha, new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 15), System.Drawing.Brushes.Gray, 2, 3);

            //render as Jpeg
            bmp.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            img = this.File(mem.GetBuffer(), "image/Jpeg");
        }

        return img;
    }
```

Here is my html:

```
<img alt="Captcha" src="@Url.Action("CaptchaImage","Account")" />
```

The problem is that CaptchaImage is not called and no image is displayed. How can I solve this problem?

### **Edit**

I use the following code to reload captcha image but it does not change image.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgCaptcha").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Account/CaptchaImage",
                success: function (result) {
                    $(this).src = result;
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you check your Controller name is right? Because I used the same code and was able to see the image rendered. And also check if there are any authentication problems for the request, I mean you placed this code in Account controller and if user was not authenticated properly then the call wouldnt be served.

Comment: What does the generated HTML for that image tag look like, i.e. what is the value for `src` actually set as when the page loads?

Comment: FWIW, why are you creating your own CAPTCHA routine anyways? First, CAPTCHAs are horrible for UX and are actually easily cracked by bots (Google just actually created and open sourced an algorithm they created to read house numbers in street view that is also very good at cracking their own CAPTCHAs). Honey pots are better and more user friendly, anyways. If you're going to insist on a CAPTCHA, though, use one of the many already out in the real world like ReCAPTCHA, which although can be cracked (see previous about Google), is at least hardened more than anything you will create on your own.

Answer (score 0):

In your image src should be image path. So you should consider do this logic before and pass path to your img source.

Comment: I added [AllowAnonymous] attribute to CaptchaImage action and `<img alt="Captcha" src="@Url.Action("CaptchaImage","Account")" />` works at the first page load and it doesn't work at subsequent ajax requests.

Comment: Can you track it with fiddler? and try to turn off cache in ajax call